# Show total count of matches

Tags: shell, ripgrep

I run `rg "\bres\b" --stats` on my code and it shows be such stats:

```
665 matches
534 matched lines
149 files contained matches
3603 files searched
33871 bytes printed
9805953 bytes searched
0.445034 seconds spent searching
0.083803 seconds
```

I only want to know that there are `665 matches`, and ideally run command like this with the output of:

```bash
$ rg "\bres\b" --total-matches
665
```

Is there a way to do it? I am not interested in grepping this stat from the output of command with `--stats`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this command shows exact same number as in `--stats`:

```bash
rg {regex} --count-matches --no-filename | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```